# Is there a limit to the label length of a text node in wxTreectrl (as returned by GetItemText)?

Tags: linux, treeview, centos7, wxwidgets, gtk3

I wonder if there is a hard limit how much data can be stored in a label of a text node? What if there are several nodes, each with say 10,000 characters? Is there a total limit for the entire tree?

Comment: do you have a problem with it?

Comment: No, the software currently works and can store quite long texts in some nodes. I just wanted to be sure texts would not be truncated at some limit or even worse: that the application could crash.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reasonable limit on the length of a label of an item in `wxTreeCtrl`. It's definitely not supposed to store any really long strings (if only because they must fit inside the window), so why would you want to do something like this? Perhaps you need to look at "client data" support of this control, allowing you to associate an arbitrary object with any item.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer; I know about the client data and already use it, but in this particular case it would only complicate the code which works fine. I just wanted to be sure that it won't break with long strings, since this is for work. Now fixing this is not a priority.